# PHP sessions and session_start()

Tags: php, session

Sorry if this is a silly question but lately I've been designing a site for a client and something strange has been happening with my sessions.

The site has a PayPal button which redirects the user to PayPal so they can confirm a payment, before being redirected to the site again.

Before the user is redirected, a load of session variables are saved. Some of them are to do with PayPal, others are to do with things on my site such as a variable to determine which user is logged in, their shopping cart items, etc.

Now, here's where things have been going wrong...

The user is redirected from checkout.php to PayPal. Before they're redirected, all session variables for the site are present (shown by var_dump and print_r). This is fine.

The user returns from PayPal to orderreview.php, but var_dump and print_r now show that the site session variables are missing, but all PayPal ones are there.

I fixed this problem by removing "session_start();" from the top of orderreview.php.

So my question is, why did removing that line fix the issue? Why wouldn't it work before?

I thought I understood PHP sessions but clearly I don't understand them as well as I thought.

I'd read this somewhere:

"As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() while the session has already been started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored."

So I was under the assumption that calling session_start at the top of the script wouldn't affect anything if a session was already started earlier.

Thanks for any answers, once again I apologise if this is a silly question.

Comment: Is `orderreview.php` its own file or is it included by some other file where `session_start()` may have already been called?

Comment: It's its own file, there's a redirect from PayPal straight to mysiteURL/orderreview.php

Comment: Ok strange, without session_start I don't see how you could get any session data at all, it shouldn't be available. What does `var_dump(session_id());` show?  It should be an empty string if no session is started.  The only thing I can think of is that maybe the `session.auto_start` setting is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's may be because that you have been redirected to another site during the process. And while you return from Paypal to your website, `session_start()` generated a new session id which your previously stored session variables are not linked to.

And when you removed `session_start()` (I don't think session should work without this on top), it used the old session id and never got regenerated. Hence, old session data are back!

This is just my assumption.

Comment: The thing is, the code is working perfectly without session_start() at the top but like you said, I don't think sessions should be working without that line either...so I'm not sure whether or not to keep it like this? It seems a bit unsafe...but I'm not sure what else to do

Comment: there is no way session could work without starting it, may be you have it started in some config file and included it on top?

Comment: Okay so on further review, it turns out I had a script included at the top of orderreview.php, which had a script included at the top of that, which called session_start() (hence sessions were working fine). 

However, this still means that having session_start() at the top of orderreview.php was causing the problems (tested this theory quite extensively, it's the only thing causing it) so I'm still stumped as to why this would be the case :/

Comment: so you had `session_start()` twice. Just echo session id just after both the session start. YOu will get to know if they are getting same session or different one. If it's same, you don't need to worry about, if it's different then your old session variables will not work.

Comment: I noticed another problem:

User buys something from the site, let's say their sessionID is "ID1"

After the user buys something from the site, they close their browser window. They open it again and go back to the site because they've forgotten to order a certain product. Their session ID is now different (we'll call it ID2).

The user is redirected to PayPal, they confirm everything, get redirected to orderreview.php, but now their session ID has gone back to ID1 again, thus some problems are caused. 

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: In other pages also have you initialized `session_start()`? Remove it from other pages where the top file (one which have session_start initialized first) is already included.

Comment: session_start() only appears in the file which is included at the top of all pages with require_once(). Anything else I could do?

Comment: When user closes the browser, either the new session will be generated or the old one based on the cookies, there can't be both.

Comment: Okay I've figured out the problem, basically I didn't realise that a script was being called which had something like:

"$_SESSION['key'] = value;"

before session_start() was called. I think the old session was being used because of this. All I know is that when I sorted that out, everything's been working like a charm. 


Thanks everyone for your help, greatly appreciated!